# php & mysql query - cannot return the variable I need from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

**update**: There must be a minor syntax error in some accompanying validation for $_GET variable. I rewrote everything carefully and the script now works. Thank you all!

I've spent more than 5 hours trying to find what's wrong with my code.

1st page: a db query retrieves some vimeo videos from the db and presents each one of them with an "edit" link which dynamically gets the video's id (vimeo 8-digit id). To do this, I just call the following function:

```
function edit_portfolio_videos() {
global $connection;
$query = "SELECT * FROM portfolio_videos ORDER BY video_id ASC";
$portfolio_videos_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
confirm_query($portfolio_videos_set);
while ($portfolio_video = mysql_fetch_array($portfolio_videos_set)) {
    echo "<iframe src=\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/";
    echo $portfolio_video['video_code'];
    echo "?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff\" width=\"400\" height=\"230\" frameborder=\"0\" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe><br />";
    echo "<a href=\"edit_portfolio_video.php?videocode={$portfolio_video['video_code']}\">Edit this Video</a>";
    }
}
```

2nd page: This is the page where each video will be edited by the administrator. Example URL would be something like "http://www.my_website.com/edit_portfolio_video.php?videocode=34956540". On this page, I use the following function to get the array from the previous page's script:

```
function get_selected_video_by_id($video_code) {
global $connection;
$query = "SELECT * FROM portfolio_videos ";
$query .= "WHERE video_code = '$video_code' ";
$query .= "LIMIT 1";
$videos_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
confirm_query($videos_set);
if ($video = mysql_fetch_array($videos_set)) {
    return $video;
} else { $video = NULL; }
```

}

and then...

```
$selected_video = get_selected_video_by_id($_GET['videocode']);
```

in order to put every kind of data related to the selected video  in the edit form:

```
<form action="edit_portfolio_video.php?videoid=<?php echo $selected_video['video_code']; ?>" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="video_title" value="<?php echo $selected_video['video_title']; ?>" />  
            </p>
            <p>Video Code (vimeo):<br />
            <input type="text" name="video_code" value="<?php echo $selected_video['video_code']; ?>" />
            </p>
            <p>Video Description:<br/>
            <textarea name="video_description" rows="5" cols="70"><?php echo $selected_video['video_description']; ?></textarea>    
            </p>
            <p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Video" />    
            </p>
</form>
```

But the form's fields don't get populated, as there seems to be a problem with the $video variable I'm trying to get (returned from get_selected_video_by_id function). The video code  is stored as "INT" (length: 11) in the database and is printed as string in the 2nd page's URL. I've tried to write the function's query in many ways but I can't get it to work.

I'd appreciate some help on this, thank you all.

Note: The confirm_query function does this simple job:

```
function confirm_query($result_set) {
if (!$result_set) {
    die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
}
```

}

Comment: Have you confirmed that $video is not null? (Are you sure get_selected_video_by_id actually returns a video?)

Comment: I just added the confirm_query() function definition.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: Note in the current stable version of PHP, they've not yet added `E_DEPRECATED` for these functions.  They are probably used in a good half of all active PHP code on the net. lol

Comment: @Orbling: That's very sad. I haven't said its deprecated, but the process has started. It'll be declared a national holiday once `mysql_* `is officially deprecated.

Comment: @TerrySeidler: $video IS actually returned as NULL. The problem is related to the query included in this function and I can't find what's wrong with that.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: It would be better if people used the modern and reliable frameworks.  However, adoption is traditionally very slow in the PHP world.  There are people who have only recently stopped using magic quotes and automatic global declaration.  ie. PHP has bigger legacy issues, probably always will.

Comment: @Orbling: That's not because of ignorant programmers, it's because sites like w3schools are still at the top of every google search in the subject. It's because outdated tutorials fill the first and second pages of google completely when you google for `mysql php`.

Comment: I agree but I'm a beginner and it's not my fault that w3schools were top results when I started learning PHP. However... could you please help me on the initial question? (lol)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: Well, information disseminates well in this age.  Unfortunately, popularity over time scales availability, rather than say current best practice.  You will have to send an email to w3schools. lol

Comment: I first have to solve this little issue and then I'll send that email lol

Comment: The script now works - there must be some kind of syntax or logic error. I rewrote the whole thing and now it works. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this instead for your get_selected_video_by_id SQL query.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM portfolio_videos WHERE video_code = ".$video_code;
```

Of course watch out for SQL injection in your parameters, and also, as someone already suggested please consider using PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: I've tried that but I get the following error: "Database query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1' at line 1".

Comment: Oops. Is your video_code not unique? Get rid of the LIMIT 1 part of the query, then. $query = "SELECT * FROM portfolio_videos WHERE video_code = ".$video_code;

Comment: video_code is not unique. I've tried your suggestion but I get this error: "Database query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1".

Comment: Try casting the video_code into an integer like this $video_code = (int) $video_code. Meanwhile, why isn't video_code unique? Doesn't really make sense to me. If it's not unique how does your application know which of the vimeo videos to load, given the ID code? :-/

Comment: Do you mean intval()?  video_code is unique as every vimeo code is unique. But video_code is not set as "unique" field in MySQL.

Comment: No, I meant $foo = (int) $bar which converts $bar into an integer. Also as gfabi said, shouldn't you be using form action="get" rather than post, since you're passing a get variable?

Comment: The form will submit to itself, I haven't worked on this yet. I have to solve this issue before moving on. Converting the varable into integer doesn't change a thing.

Comment: Honestly, I really don't know what's wrong here. Maybe you should run a sample query in your mySQL admin interface (command line, client or PHPMyadmin) and see if anything comes up.

Comment: I'll try that, thank you very much. In the meantime, I'd really appreciate any kind of suggestion for this issue from other fellows :)

Comment: The script now works - there must be some kind of syntax or logic error. I rewrote the whole thing and now it works. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Glad you got it working! Maybe you should accept one of the answers that helped you. Cheers!!

Comment: Yes thank you! 
What if no answer gave the final solution? Do you think I should accept an answer eitherway?

Answer (score 0):

Your Form seems strange:
you are using a POST mode to pass a GET value (edit_portfolio_video.php?videoid=...etc...).
But this shouldn't be the problem.

In this line:

`$selected_video = get_selected_video_by_id($_GET['videocode']);`

are you sure the GET parameter you are passing is videocode? Or is it videoid?

Comment: Aha! I didn't even see that POST/GET thing in the form. Too many things wrong with the code in the OP.

Comment: Yes, I'm passing video_code, not video_id. I should have renamed this function as I was initially passing the selected video's code into the URL by using its database id.